# What exactly is kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault?

Tags: ios, core-graphics

The doc tautologically explains `kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault` as:

> The default byte order.

But what exactly is this *default byte order*?

Comment: It is the endian order of the host machine/device.

Comment: @matt I guessed that. But how about 16-bit vs 32-bit? It says nothing about it. My guess is 32 but want to be sure.

Comment: I think the point is that if you saved as default you can retrieve as default, without having to worry about its meaning. If you are retrieving from a bitmap you didn't create, you must say explicitly what the format is.

Comment: @matt ideally `CGImageGetBitmapInfo` should never return `kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault`. It should always return one of the other 4 values. However in reality, it returns `kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault for some images. In my current particular case it's 32-bit.

Comment: @matt: I got some images with `kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault` on iOS (little endian), and it seems to be big-endian